# Do nuget package project references get messed up when packages stored locally on a diff folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

When another developer gets latest from the repository in TFS, the references for each project in the solution don't seem to link up correctly.

From what I assumed, if you use nuget, it will automatically pull the necessary libraries for you no?   Do I have to go into vs.net and tell it to download the libraries?

Or did I add something into TFS that I shouldn't have such that it is assuming my packages are stored at a particular path when they might not be when another developer downloads the repository?

This is vs.net 2010.

Comment: Are the libraries themselves in TFS? By default, TFS won't prompt you to check-in `.dll` files.

Comment: Ryan, no they aren't in TFS just looked, but what's the point of having nuget, why can I just download them on the new computer?  I don't even see the option?

Comment: You need to enable NuGet Package Restore. Tools -> Options -> Package Manager : Make sure "Allow Nuget to download missing packages during build" is checked.

Comment: Did that, and it didn't work.

Comment: Is your question how to configure nuget to get the latest and greatest versions of your dependencies without persisting them in source control?

Comment: my question is, if I am using nuget, and the packages are in tfs, when another developer pulls the code down, and the dll's are in tfs, how can they get them?  I can see 'installed packages' but it has a manage button only, not download.  And they aren't even downloaded on the file system but it doesn't let you 'download all packages now' button or something.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your folder structure in your question? Also please include @RyanGates in reply comments, so that I will be notified that you responded. There should be a packages folder at the solution level and a repositories.config. Then all your dependencies should be under that folder.

Comment: The other computer is getting this error after I checked all dll's into TFS and they got latest:  "Unable to copy file c:\....\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.207....\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.xml' to 'bin\System.web.http.xml"  Access to the path 'bin\System.Web.Http.xml" is denied.

Answer (score 3):

I had some similar issues so I switched NuGet modes to not [commit packages to source control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).

1. Got to **Options** -> **Package Manager** -> **General** and check the "Allow NuGet to download missing packeges during build" CheckBox and press "OK".
2. Right click on the solution in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer and select "Enable NuGet Package Restore".

I also added the contents of the **.nuget** and **packages** folders (which the previous steps created in the solution's folder) to the solution in [solution folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haytww03%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  This way I can right click on the solution and select "Check In..." and all relevant files will be checked in.  If you do this then it is very important that none of the package files (like .dll files) are included in the solution or TFS as this will cause NuGet to not work correctly.  If you choose not to do this then you will need to check in your changes using the **Pending Changes** window or by right clicking on the solution folder in **Source Control Explorer** and selecting "Check In Pending Changes..."

My .nuget solution folder contains the following files:

- Notes.txt describing how I set NuGet up, why I set it up the way I did, and any usage notes/issues.
- NuGet.config
- NuGet.exe
- NuGet.targets

My packages solution folder contains the following files:

- repositories.config

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the "Allow NuGen to download missing packages" didn't cut it for me.  I noticed that there was a "packages" folder created for nuget stuff in my solution.  I had checked this in, but TFS by default filters out .dll files.  So I had to go back into the "packages" folder in my source control explorer, and add the .dlls and check in the change.

For example this is the steps in Visual Studio 2013 for checking in the EntityFramework .dll I got from NuGet (this assumes you have already checked in your "packages" folder without the .dlls)

1. In source control explorer find your packages folder
2. Open the folder by clicking the little arrow to the left
3. Find the "lib" folder inside the folder you opened
4. Right click on the "net45" folder (or "net40" or whatever) and choose the context option to "add items to folder.
5. From the Add to source control pop-up, double click the "net45" folder.
6. You should see some .dll file(s) that were excluded on your initial check in
7. click the missing file and hit "next" button below...
8. Hopefully the .dll is in the "Items to add" tab now...  if not hit the button at the bottom of the screen to "include items".
9. Hit finish button
10. Check in this pending change
11. Now do a get of the solution in the new workspace.