# Why does creating a MVC4 application use nuget by default?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

Is there a way to remove nuget from a solution, I just create a brand new MVC4 project and I noticed the dll's are using nuget packages.

I'm having issues with nuget and TFS, and it is just a headache trying to get a co-workers computer setup and I just want to disconnect from nuget if possible. (see my other question: [Do nuget package project references get messed up when packages stored locally on a diff folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953611/do-nuget-package-project-references-get-messed-up-when-packages-stored-locally-o))

Comment: You weren't very descriptive in that linked question, you enabled the option in VS but it 'didn't work'. What didn't work? Also, you could just add the NuGet assemblies (package folder) into version control.

Comment: Use the "ASP.NET Empty Web Application" template and add your references manually?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not easy.

NuGet packages are basically just zip files with .dlls, config transforms, content, and other things, and normally you'd just use Package Explorer to download the package, extract the dlls to a "lib" folder, then import the references.

The AspNetMvc package, however, has a number of dependencies, which means you'll have to download each package in the tree indivdiually. It's not that bad, but it involves getting:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
- Microsoft.AspNet.Razor
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages

Once you have the dlls from those packages, you can add them to the "lib" folder, and reference them as per normal.